# How to access nested plist directories cocos2dx?

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

Im new to programming and Im having trouble accessing directories that are nested inside other directories. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Example:
[Nested Dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQleQ.png)

Code with Cocos2dx that I use to access first directory:

```
__String *fileName = __String::create( "InventoryData.plist" );

__Dictionary *dictionary = __Dictionary::createWithContentsOfFile(fileName->getCString() );
```

I have tried using `__Dictionary::createWithDirectory("Nested Root")` but that doesn't work because it can't find it. Im sure there is an easy way to do it I just can't seem to find it. Sorry for noob question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this micro `CCDICT_FOREACH(__dict__, __el__)` that traverse your dictionary.

```
__Dictionary *dist=__Dictionary::createWithContentsOfFile("xyz.plist");

DictElement *d=nullptr;
CCDICT_FOREACH(dist, d){

  CCLOG("%s",d->getStrKey());  // It will print all key name

  if(*d->getStrKey()==*"texture"){  //Match with particular Key(here I'm using texture)

       __Dictionary *nested=(__Dictionary*)d->getObject();  // downcast nested dictionary.

       // Now you've nested dictionary you can get value or if having nested dictionary iterate again

       CCLOG("%s",nested->valueForKey("width")->getCString());  
       CCLOG("%s",nested->valueForKey("height")->getCString());  

   }
}
```

Comment: could you explain what *"texture" is. And why i cant replace it with a string variable.

Comment: "texture" is a string literal having type `const char *`, so i dereferencing to get what data that pointer points. texture is just an entry in my .plist which is   itself a __Dictionary inside his parent dictionary *dist

Comment: I am having an issue when two entries have the same starting character. They seem to confuse each other any ideas?

Comment: I don't think so, there will some confusion, it matches with whole string not only first character e.g. "texture" is different to "texture1"

Comment: I changed the if to this: if(d->getStrKey()=="texture"){} and it works good now. I think it is because cons char can only hold 1 char is that correct? I'm new to programming and I'm not sure why could you please explain. Edit:i have to use strncmp